# Can a linq query using join do the select part using a lambda function with no extension methods?

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to substitute the static function here with a lamda function using linq with no extension methods:

```
static TransferResponseDto DoIt(IMapper mapper, Transfer t, Customer c)
{
    TransferResponseDto dto =  mapper.Map<TransferResponseDto>(t);
    dto.CustomerName = c.Name;

    return dto;
}

[Authorize(Policy=PoliciesDefinitions.RequiresTransferList)]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IList<TransferResponseDto>>> Get()
{
    IQueryable<Transfer> querable = ValidationFilters.AddFiltersForClaim(_dbContext.Transfers, HttpContext,
        Permissions.TransfersList.ToString());

    var finalQuery = (from t in querable
        join customer in _dbContext.Customers on t.CustomerId equals customer.Id
        select DoIt(_mapper, t,customer));


    var dtos = await finalQuery.ToListAsync();

    return dtos;
}
```

I have seen a lot of examples using the Join extension method and of course a lot of examples newing in the select part like:

```
var query = from post in database.Posts
            join meta in database.Post_Metas on 1 equals 1
            where post.ID == id
            select new { Post = post, Meta = meta };
```

But how about doing something like:

```
var finalQuery = (from transfer in querable
        join customer in _dbContext.Customers on t.CustomerId equals customer.Id
        select (transfer, customer) => { ... }
```

for me this always shows an error saying that join can't infere the arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Note that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions):

> A query expression of the form
>
> `from x in e select v`
>
> is translated into
>
> `(e).Select ( x => v )`

Hence what your'e trying to do is translating into something like (note the double `=>`):

```
( ... ).Select((transfer, customer) => ... => ...)
```

which technically could have been compiled if what you intended was *returning* a lambda expression, but:

1. I understand you don't want to do that,
2. Even if you did want to do that, you'd have to exlicitly* declare the types, 
    which you can't because your'e dealing with anonymous objects.

   *To illustrate, let's take a simpler example:
    `posts.Select<string, Func<string, string>>(r => (ra => ra));`
    As you can see, I had to explicitly declare the `Select` type, otherwise I'd get an error.

Thus, to achieve what you intend, simply call a method:

```
var finalQuery = 
   from transfer in queryable
   join customer in _dbContext.Customers on t.CustomerId equals customer.Id
   select DoWhatever(transfer, customer);
```